# Populating drop down list does not work after deploying to Tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, struts

I am trying to populate a dropdown list in JSP using the Struts framework and MySQL database.

The dropdown list is working fine when running it from Eclipse, but after creating WAR file and deploying it into another Tomcat server, I am not getting the dropdown list.

What could be the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your jars were probably not deployed correctly.

check the lib directory (the location of your jars at tomcat) or the library you planned to deploy the jars.

it would help if you post the error you get.

Answer (score 0):

Are the dropdown values coming off the database? Please check the Tomcat logs to see if you got any error messages. Check whether you have everything getting generated in the war file. Also, please post you code here so that we can assist you in a better manner.